# PHP 8, function alias compatibility `getdir()`

Tags: php, alias, backwards-compatibility, php-8

While testing if my [php](/questions/tagged/php) script is [php-8](/questions/tagged/php-8) compatible, I got stuck on the following code:

```php
function getDir($a, $o = 2) {
    $d = Floor($a / $o);
    return ($d % 2 === 0);
}
```

Prior to [php-8](/questions/tagged/php-8), this worked fine, however, on [php-8](/questions/tagged/php-8) it throws:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getDir()

<sup>[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IvoL1)</sup>

---

After searching for a while, I've found that [php-8](/questions/tagged/php-8) introduced a new alias to `dir()`:

```php
/** @param resource $context */
function getdir(string $directory, $context = null): Directory|false {}
```

<sup>[php-src line 709](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4c6533c257cfabd5dd78988bb277f410b2778140/ext/standard/basic_functions.stub.php#L709)</sup>

#### Questions

- Can I get my code to work on [php-8](/questions/tagged/php-8) **without** renaming the function?
- Is there a list of all new function aliases?

  - [`dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php) doesn't mention the alias
  - [PHP 8 Release Announcement](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php) doesn't mention the alias either

Comment: The `getdir` alias seems to be very old (< PHP 5) https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-4.4.9/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L714. I dont see any notices in the php migration guide regarding function redeclaration, maybe thats a bug that was fixed with PHP 8

Comment: The merge of the PHP 8 branch didn't introduce this. https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/bfbac70ec5d2380adbf88211da313554d0058af9#diff-96c05a0551ccbeca3ff610c111f88b54a0d727888cf353f477ea8dc951a18637

Comment: @ADyson Well, *something did*: https://3v4l.org/Zgork

Comment: @deceze I didn't doubt it. But the code itself referenced by the OP has been there a long time, that's all I was saying. Perhaps there is some other non-obvious change which made it become active in some way - I don't claim to understand how PHP is actually built. From a read of the release notes and the list of incompatible changes in 8.0 I can't see anything which looks like it would be a root cause. But it must be there in some form, somewhere.

Comment: `Can I get my code to work on php-8 without renaming the function`...not unless you change its scope (e.g. put it inside a class, perhaps).

Comment: I'm not smart enough to read through the PHP compiler code completely, but [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79382) references [this patch](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/53eee290b6f5ca531aef19885a392c939013ce36) which targeted PHP 8, and in `function_exists` I can see a call to `zend_string_tolower`, and I'm wondering if that is related to this. A simpler test for the OP's problem is https://3v4l.org/P4lea

Comment: Yeah, reading through that code it appears that `zend_hash_exists` is just called with a lowercase version of the function's name, and the hash table probably includes functions and aliases.

Comment: I submitted this to the [PHP bug database](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80914). Although I do agree that naming a user-land function the same as a built-in function is asking for trouble, doing the same with an undocumented (as far as I can tell) alias shouldn't be expected to break. I think that all function aliases that core supports should be listed in the documentation at a minimum, even on a "function aliases please don't use page". It would be a bonus if the testing function could report it as an alias, but I don't think the engine is able to differentiate at that point.

Comment: The plot thickens: it's not a case-sensitivity issue, the function *really didn't exist*: https://3v4l.org/dCpeh And yet it was there in the source all along. Something seriously weird has happened here.

Comment: I could have sworn that I tested `function_exists('getdir')` but I must have done it locally in PHP 8 only. Thanks for looking into this further @IMSoP

Comment: Since you were interested in preserving the timeline, I've added a small section to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Update **Monday, 12 April 2021**: Many thanks to @IMSoP for creating a [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6855/files) regarding this 'bug'.

Answer (score 14):

Short answer: Whoopsie

Long answer: https://externals.io/message/113982

At the moment, I would plan on this being gone by 8.0.5  Sorry for the break, and thanks to Chris for filing a bug report abut this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80914

Answer (score 11):

This turned out to be a lot more interesting than I expected.

The short answer is that getdir() really is new in PHP 8.0.0, but this was a mistake, and it will probably be removed in 8.0.4 or 8.0.5.

The interesting part is that getdir() is not in fact an alias, but the real name of the function internally; it's just that until 8.0, it was only accessible via its alias, dir(). To explain that, we have to go back more than 20 years...

---

The [dir()](https://php.net/dir) function was added in PHP 3.0. For whatever reason - perhaps a last-minute change of name - the C function that implemented it was called "php3_getdir" not "php3_dir". That didn't matter, because every function name was mapped explicitly, like this:

```c
function_entry php3_dir_functions[] = {
    {"opendir",     php3_opendir,   NULL},
    {"closedir",    php3_closedir,  NULL},
    {"chdir",       php3_chdir,     NULL},
    {"rewinddir",   php3_rewinddir, NULL},
    {"readdir",     php3_readdir,   NULL},
    {"dir",         php3_getdir,    NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

Not long after, PHP 4 came along, and function definitions [moved to using macros](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/7a167cd0c1f6ee7c0dce0196b5ca9209a54f534c#diff-a6738c9e7e606e49fc4e7225c281deca86191ada31a5dc077169418541541d1cL59) to match the C name to the PHP name. Since the name of the function and implementation didn't match, "dir" ended up labelled as an "alias"; but no extra entry was added for "getdir":

```c
static zend_function_entry php_dir_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(opendir,     NULL)
    PHP_FE(closedir,    NULL)
    PHP_FE(chdir,       NULL)
    PHP_FE(rewinddir,   NULL)
    PHP_FE(readdir,     NULL)
    PHP_FALIAS(dir,     getdir, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

An alias without a target doesn't really make sense (and there was a PHP_NAMED_FE macro for just this purpose) but it worked, so I guess nobody noticed.

In fact, through all the changes of PHP 5 and PHP 7, it carried on working, [with basically the same line of C code right up to 7.4](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4.0/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L3248).

```c
PHP_FALIAS(dir,  getdir, arginfo_dir)
```

During the work on PHP 8, however, a system was built to generate internal function information from PHP "stubs". As part of this [stubs were added for all function aliases](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/736b22dc0b2fc36e9bd87f2ee5af8c4b2be9fd3d#diff-96c05a0551ccbeca3ff610c111f88b54a0d727888cf353f477ea8dc951a18637R723), and getdir() ended up with [its own stub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0.0/ext/standard/basic_functions.stub.php#L698):

```php
/** @param resource $context */
function getdir(string $directory, $context = null): Directory|false {}

/**
 * @param resource|null $context
 * @alias getdir
 */
function dir(string $directory, $context = null): Directory|false {}
```

This was then used to re-generate the C definitions, and finally [getdir() had its own function entry](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0.0/ext/standard/basic_functions_arginfo.h#L3150)

```c
ZEND_FE(getdir, arginfo_getdir)
ZEND_FALIAS(dir, getdir, arginfo_dir)
```

This caused getdir() to be a real built-in function name, and meant you couldn't have a function with the same name.

---

From there, four things have happened:

- 29th March 2021: [0stone0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625547/0stone0) posted this question.
- [Chris Haas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231316/chris-haas) tried to hunt down the issue, and opened [a bug on the PHP bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80914), thinking that the issue related to case sensitivity. They also confirmed that getdir() was the only alias in basic_functions.stub.php not in the manual.
- 6th April 2021: Thinking I was going to make a quick documentation fix, I got interested, and disappeared down the above rabbit hole. I [posted my findings to the PHP internals mailing list](https://externals.io/message/113982) and went to bed an hour later than I intended.
- Sara Golemon (one of the PHP 8.0 Release Managers) replied agreeing that it should be treated as a bug and reverted in the next 8.0.x release. She also [posted an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977672/157957) since I hadn't yet.